# Javascript if conditional for a CSS value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I'm trying to write a JavaScript conditional which states, "If the #inner id's 'top' value is currently less than 500px then decrease it by 15px."

I am using jQuery and the code works fine if I remove the conditional.

But the following does not work:

```
if parseInt($("#inner").css("top"), 10 < 500 {
    $("#inner").css("top", parseInt($("#inner").css("top"), 10) + 15 + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax errors, several of them ?
Try seperating it a little so you see what's going on :

```
var top = parseInt( $("#inner").css("top"), 10 );

if ( top  < 500 ) {
    $("#inner").css("top", top + 15);
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot. My code is a lot easier to understand now. I didn't understand that in JavaScript an if conditional needs surrounding parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your syntax.

```
var top = parseInt($("#inner").css("top"), 10);
if (top < 500) {
    $("#inner").css("top", (top + 15) + "px");
}
```

Would be good to read about if statetement here : [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)